# Linear Transformation $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation such that:

The null space of the standard matrix $[A]$ is the line in $R2$ with equation $x − 3y = 0$

$ \ A([4,3])=[8,-4,2]$

Find the standard matrix $[A]$ of $A$

I don't quite know where to start off. Can somebody give me a hint? Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

You know that $A([4,3])=[8,-4,2]$. And you also know that $A([3,1])=[0,0,0]$. So, since$$[1,0]=-\frac15[4,3]+\frac35[3,1],$$you know that $A([4,3])=-\frac15[8,-4,2]$. Now, use a similar computation to get $A([0,1])$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

$A(3,1)=(0,0,0)$ and $A(4,3)=(8,-4,2)$. As A is a linear operator then:

$A(3,1)=3A(1,0) +A(0,1)$ and $A(4,3)=4A(1,0) +3A(0,1)$

Then just solve in order to $A(1,0)$ and $A(0,1)$ and finally $A(x,y)=xA(1,0)+yA(0,1)$ for any x and y.